# How can I enter data into a custom-handled input field?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension has a context menu with items. What I'd like it to do: is when I right-click a `editable` HTML element (e.g. input or textarea) and then select and click on an item in my menu - some value defined by my extension gets entered into the input.

For now I have realised that:

```
document.activeElement.value = myValue
```

works alright with simple inputs.

Problems start when there is an input with custom `onChange` event handling, e.g. a calendar or a phone input, or currency input - that transforms user-input in some way.

Since I am setting a value directly onto the element - the handling logic gets omitted, which causes all manner of problems.

Since JavaScript doesn't allow for KeySend-like features - what are my options here?

I have thought about testing tools like Puppeteer or Cypress - but they all seem not to be packageable into an extension. Puppeteer does have such an option, but it still requires a node instance running to connect to. And I would like my extension to be solely client-sided and distributed in Chrome webstore - so I cannot ask my users to spin up a node server.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is a built-in DOM method [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand).
In case of an extension, use this code in the [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

```
// some.selector may be `input` or `[contenteditable]` for richly formatted inputs
const el = document.querySelector('some.selector');
el.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'new text');
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})); // usually not needed
```

**It imitates physical user input** into the currently focused DOM element so all the necessary events will be fired (like `beforeinput`, `input`) with `isTrusted` field set to true. On some pages the `change` event should be additionally dispatched as shown above.

You may want to select the current text to replace it entirely instead of appending:

```
replaceValue('some.selector', 'new text');

function replaceValue(selector, value) {
  const el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (el) {
    el.focus();
    document.execCommand('selectAll');
    if (!document.execCommand('insertText', false, value)) {
      // Fallback for Firefox: just replace the value
      el.value = 'new text';
    }
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})); // usually not needed
  }
  return el;
}
```

Note that despite execCommand being marked as obsolete in 2020, it'll work in the foreseeable future because a new editing API specification is not finished yet, and knowing how slow such things usually move it may take another 5-20 years.

Comment: This does not work with CKEditor 5.

Answer (score 11):

Because `document.execCommand()` has been depredated, I'm now using the following code which works well:

```
function imitateKeyInput(el, keyChar) {
  if (el) {
    const keyboardEventInit = {bubbles:false, cancelable:false, composed:false, key:'', code:'', location:0};
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", keyboardEventInit));
    el.value = keyChar;
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", keyboardEventInit));
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})); // usually not needed
  } else {
    console.log("el is null");    
  }
}
```

The following code can only work on ordinary websites, but it is invalid for strong websites (e.g. Facebook).

```
function fireKeyEvent(el, evtType, keyChar) {
  el.addEventListener(evtType, function(e) {el.value += e.key;}, false);
  el.focus();
  const keyboardEventInit = {bubbles:false, cancelable:false, composed:false, key:keyChar, code:'', location:0};
  var evtObj = new KeyboardEvent(evtType, keyboardEventInit);
  el.dispatchEvent(evtObj);
}
```

Comment: Great answer to solve this issue after the execCommand deprecation.

Comment: But does not work for Angular

Comment: This does not work with CKEditor 5.