# Modifying view via chrome extension doesn't change it's model in angular2 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-chrome-extension, angular2-forms

I am developing a **chrome extension** for a website which is build on `angular2`. When I try to insert some value in an input field it doesn't change it's `model`. I am not sure why angular2 doesn't detect changes. Kindly guide me how to do it.

Angular2 text text field code is as

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
```

Chrome extension code

```
$('input[name="username"]').val("abcd");
```

It injects the value in view but model is still null

Comment: You need to dispatch a `'change'` event or use document.execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: I tried document.execCommand and it works fine with text field and text area but doesn't works with select element. Kindly suggest

Comment: Use the first suggestion in my comment.

Comment: It's working with element.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")); Thanks