# use javascript set value to input ,the input value will disappear when it's on focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i have try to fill some value into input field by javascript(chrome extension)which belong to a form , the value seems not update, and will disappear when i click the other area of the page ,
my code is simple

```
document.getElementById("editGiftCardNumber").value = "12345";
document.getElementById("editGiftCardNumber").setAttribute('value','12345');
```

also try to use

```
 setTimeout(function()
```

e.g. in https://www.elementaryrobotics.com/
, i try to set value in chrome console

```
input = document.getElementById("comp-jpua0zn5input");
input.value="123";
```

you will see the 123 is shown in input, if I click other area of the page, the 123 will disappear, how to solve it ?

Comment: I checked the website you linked, set value with chrome console, clicked elsewhere, and the value did not change. Only if you click on the select box above it, it resets the value. What are the exact steps you are taking?

Comment: It has to do with a blur Event. I had to focus on the Element after changing the value. The value went blank when I blurred out.

Comment: True, also it's a React website

Comment: Does this help: [Chrome extension: enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849) ?

Comment: thanks this helps,save my day