# only input from keyboard is validated not from autofill

Tags: google-chrome-extension

hi i am making an autofill chrome extension in javascript.
and i want to use that extension to autofill my data on whatever website i want.
it is working fine ,when i click, the extension details filled automatically but when i press
submit button it is saying error please fill in the name field, even i already filled it using autofill extension.
but samething when i give input from keyboard instead of using extension then there is no error thrown.

My pseudocode is given this

```
<form _ngcontent-c26="" class="form-inline ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" novalidate> 

<input _ngcontent-c29="" class="form-control input-xs ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" id="psgn-name" 
name="psgn-name" size="24" style="font-size: 1.1rem" type="text" placeholder=" Name" maxlength="16">

<button _ngcontent-c26="" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Continue </button>

</form>
```

even no any "required" attribute is there then why i am getting this error
on pressing submit it is saying error name is required . can someone help me to get out of this.

Comment: [Chrome extension: enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: actually i want my autofill data to be validated but its not getting validated

Comment: only when i give input from keyboard its is validated thats what i dont want, i want it to validate all the input whether it is from autofill or manually entered through keyboard

Comment: The linked answer shows how to set the value properly.

Comment: it is saying undefined

Comment: That answer works when used correctly so I can't help as I don't know who is "it" and where it's "saying".