# jQuery (or Javascript) imitating clicking on a field and typing the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I am trying to create a userscript (Javascript) to run in TamperMonkey for Chrome on http://www.Bitmex.com, which has the goal of imitating clicking on an input field, changing its value with keyboard strokes. Reason is the site seems to monitor if the value of the field was changed without manual input, and not allowing it. What is the way to do it in jQuery (or Javascript). Below is what I tried (firing change event and click event), but it didn't work.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         BitMex
// @namespace    https://bitmex.com/
// @grant        none
// @include      https://bitmex.com/*
// @include      https://www.bitmex.com/*
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
var $ = window.jQuery;

$(window).bind("load", function() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        var keyLocation = ["Standard", "Left", "Right", "Numpad", "Mobile", "Joystick"][e.location];
        // Pressed ALT -> SELL
        if (keyLocation == 'Left' && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
            $("#orderQty").trigger("click");
            $("#orderQty").val("2");
            $('#orderQty').focus();
            $('#orderQty').keydown();
            $('#orderQty').keypress();
            $('#orderQty').keyup();
            $('#orderQty').change();
            $('#orderQty').blur();
        }
    }, false);
});
```

I also tried the "sendKeys" (http://bililite.com/blog/2011/01/23/improved-sendkeys/) but the field is of type "number" and is giving me this error in the console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection.
```

Comment: Simply use document.execCommand ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)).

Comment: Does it work on Chrome?

Comment: Yes of course. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Ok nevermind it worked thanks! Can you please post as an answer to accept.

Comment: Also, it seems the click command is also facing the same issue. Any way to execute the click command just like a mouse click too?

Comment: Try the standard dispatchEvent, not jQuery.

Comment: I did. Same issue. It seems they monitor the delay between the commands and if it seems instant then they block it. I will try to delay a bit.