# Chrome extension: enter value in text field via UI instead of javascript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The input field I am trying to utilize does not respond to changes to only it's value so I'm wondering if there's some API similar to selenium that will allow me to perform UI testing-like actions so I can enter in the value via clicking, entering keys rather than via javascript? Basically, is it possible to input a value into a search box WITHOUT javascript within a chrome extension?

Comment: [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: There's another possibility: [chrome.automation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/automation#property-AutomationNode-setValue) but I haven't used it.