# Can a website detect usage of TamperMonkey scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I had a question about Tampermonkey detection on websites. I've viewed a lot of the questions on here but haven't found an answer specific to my case.

I'm wanting a script that will auto-fill some input boxes in for me on a website and preferably click the submit button for me.

Looking at other answers, some have mentioned that it's possible for a script-generated mouse click to be detected. I'm not sure if this is correct or not. If it is and I avoid automated clicks, can an input box value change be detected?

I would be changing the value by doing the following:
$('#name').val('Jeff')

This isn't me trying to abuse any system, it's more of an ease of life script.

Thanks.

The code I'm using:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
  document.getElementById("name").value = "Jeff";
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure script generated mouse events will have `isTrusted: false`, whereas user generated clicks will have `isTrusted: true`.

Comment: That's what I read in another answer* as well but they mentioned it was for Opera, I wasn't too sure about that so wanted to make sure. Thanks

Comment: I think you can change the value of inputs without firing any events. Unless that's what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to be able to change the values without any detection. My goal is just to keep it appearing that I'm a normal user without any automation.

Comment: Does `inputElement.value = 'my value'` not work?

Comment: That works, didn't know my other method was an issue. So what I'm doing is, waiting for a button to be clicked before changing a value.

So document.addEventListener('click',.....document.getElementById("name").value = "Jeff";

And that works for me, so nothing there would be detected?

Comment: I edited my original question to show the code I'm using. Right now I'm looking for any manual click from me and then I change the value.

Comment: I don’t think that’s detectable. As far as I’m aware

Comment: Great, thanks for help mate. Much appreciated.

Comment: On some sites changing the `value` will be ignored so you can use document.execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: Changing the value works for me but looking at your answer, you say that "execCommand imitates physical user input". Does changing the value like I have not do this? Or are both methods of changing the value fine/undetectable and this is just an alternative? Thanks.