# How to send keypresses to input field?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

This opens a Zip code field. If I enter a Zip code manually a list of providers is shown. If I set the value with the script the list is not shown. So I am trying to simulate keypresses, but it is not working.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     titantv
// @version  1
// @include  https://www.titantv.com/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var create = document.getElementById('ctl00_Main_TVL_ctl00_Nav_ctl00_AddLineup');
create.click();

setTimeout(function(){
    var broadcast = document.getElementById('broadcast');
    broadcast.click();

    setTimeout(function(){
        var zip = document.getElementById('zipEntryInput');
        zip.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'50'}));
    }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Try to focus it and use document.execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: This doesn't work and returns false:

    document.getElementById('zipEntryInput').focus();document.execCommand('InsertText', false, zipCode);

But this returns true:

    document.queryCommandSupported('insertText');

Comment: I guess it means the element is neither an HTML input nor contenteditable. Try your original code but fix the parameters per [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/596481)

Comment: The element is a simple input field:
<input type="text" id="zipEntryInput" maxlength="5" tabindex="0">
I've tried many combinations of parameters to no avail.