# Textarea's value gets cleared when focused

Tags: jquery, instagram, tampermonkey

I'm trying to use tampermonkey to automatically comment on instagram images.

The comment element is a textarea:

```
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="Ypffh" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"></textarea>
```

This is the only textarea in the page, I'm selecting it using:

```
let commentElement = $('textarea');
```

I have tried setting the value using:

```
commentElement.val('test comment');
```

This works and sets the value. But does not enable the `Post` button:

```
<button class="sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     " disabled="" type="submit">Post</button>
```

I tried removing `disabled` and then clicking on `Post` button, but submission was not done (as no click happened). I tried clicking both using jQuery and manually.

The confusing part is that even though `commentElement.val('test comment');` sets the value, as soon as I manually click on textarea, the value gets cleared. The value gets cleared only if I have set it using the script. If I input the value manually, value persist even if focus changes.

I've tried using keyboard events to set the value (after setting the focus to the textarea element):

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keypress');
event.keyCode = 57;
event.which   = 57;
event.altKey  = false;
event.ctrlKey = false;
event.shiftKey= false;
event.target  = window;
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

or

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = "Q";
commentElement.trigger(e);
```

or

```
var ev = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {bubbles : true, cancelable : true, key : "Q", char : "Q", shiftKey : true});
commentElement.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

But they didn't change textarea's value. Any suggestion for setting the value?

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm it worked. I spent all day looking for something like this, but didn't know what to look for.