# Fake Keyboard Event and Catch in JQuery App watching for keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

### Problem

I am trying to extend a web app with a Chrome extension. Now, I need to automate a step in the webapp. At that step, the web app has a disabled button and asks to input a specific string. I am able to input the string using:

```js
// Let's say the input element is in the input variable.
input.value = "required string"
```

It does not enable the button. It only does when I manually type in the input box. I tried debugging, the application is watching for the `keyup` event using jQuery. Now, it makes sense that it doesn't get enabled because that event is not fired.

### What I tried?

I tried faking the keyboard events using:

```js
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',  {'key':'KEY_HERE'}));
```

But it is not captured by the input and the button remains disabled. I have also tried `input.focus()` and `input.select()` etc to bring focus as that's something I found in a few places. But that didn't work either.

I am not sure what I am missing here or if that's even possible.

Comment: Try [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: @wOxxOm I just tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Assuming you did it correctly as shown in the answer, the only other method is to inspect/debug the page script in devtools and see maybe it wants some other events too like `focus` and so on.

Comment: @wOxxOm [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-moon-86c67) I have created a quick sandbox with your code and also added listeners to the events. Apparently they are not being triggered by using `execCommand` command. Regarding debugging the script, they're minified I guess and I can't inspect them.  The only way is to hit & trial.

Comment: Yeah, one of those "smart" apps... I guess then you'll have to use your initial approach but more fields should be initialized e.g. `which` with the key code, `keyCode`, maybe some others.

Comment: I have tried that as well with a complete options object, like `key`, `keyCode`, `code`, `which`, `metaKey`, `ctrl/shiftKey`. Didn't work.

Comment: @wOxxOm apparently I solved it. Sharing the solution below for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatching a keypress with the following way,

```js
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',  {'key':'KEY_HERE'}));
```

or using `execCommand` as @wOxxOm described, doesn't dispatch all the events which come with physically typing something in `<input/>` tag.

So, if you have a similar use case, you need to figure out which event the app is watching/catching and separately dispatch that event. For me, dispatching a `change` event after simply setting the value worked for me.

```js
input.value = "required string";

input.dispatchEvent(
  new Event('change', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
}))
```

`input` event is another commonly used one.