# How to autofill Google form using JS

Tags: javascript, google-forms, tampermonkey, autofill

I have simple Google Form(https://forms.gle/7xRp2Ft4Z2TZBLUY8) and I need to fill it many times with random answers. I use tampermonkey for my scipt. But google forms don't see the answer without click on input field and click on space button. So, the question is how to put space on input field using JS?

````
// @name         name
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @description  test
// @author       You
// @match        https://docs.google.com/forms/*
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var formUrl = 'url';

(function() {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/forms/d') === 0) { // Form
      submitRandomForm();
    } else if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/forms/u') === 0) { // Submitted
      window.location.href = formUrl;
    }

     function submitRandomForm() {
      //q1
      document.querySelector("UID").click(); 
      document.querySelector("UID").value = "TEXT"; 
      //q2
      document.querySelector("UID").click(); 
      ddocument.querySelector("UID").value = "TEXT"; 
      //q3
      document.querySelector("UID").click(); 
      document.querySelector("UID").value = "TEXT"; 
      
      
      //Submit
      document.querySelector("UID").click();
    }

    function goBackToForm() {
      window.location.href = 'URL';
    }
  });
})();```
````

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the input field is empty now(

Comment: Sounds like you didn't focus the element as shown in that answer.

Comment: `el = document.querySelector("div.quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInputArea input[autocomplete=email]");
      el.focus();
      console.log(el);
      document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'example@example.com');`
and the log is 


```<input type="email" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="email" tabindex="0" aria-label="Your e-mail " required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="">```

Comment: I don't see any elements matching your selector in the form page linked in the question...

Comment: `el = document.querySelector("div.quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInputArea input[aria-labelledby=i1]");
el.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'testtesttest');`

question1 selector

Comment: Turns out execCommand doesn't work in Firefox, but works in Chrome. Try adding dispatchEvent line (in my example) to your original code.

Comment: I tested my script in Chrome and it doesn't work, can u send your code?

Comment: Your last code in the comments works for me.

Comment: Turns out that it works but not always. I made 25 answers and about 5-6 is not empty

Comment: I guess you need to wait until the form initializes - use `setTimeout`.

Comment: `setTimeout` solve my problem, thanks u