# Reply to tweet in chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, twitter

I am using following code.

```
var articles = $("article");
    var reply_array = [];

    articles.each(function (increment, current) {
      var reply_g = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < $(current).find("svg").length; i++) {
        reply_g = $(current).find("svg g path").eq(i).attr("d");

        if (
          reply_g ==
          "M14.046 2.242l-4.148-.01h-.002c-4.374 0-7.8 3.427-7.8 7.802 0 4.098 3.186 7.206 7.465 7.37v3.828c0 .108.044.286.12.403.142.225.384.347.632.347.138 0 .277-.038.402-.118.264-.168 6.473-4.14 8.088-5.506 1.902-1.61 3.04-3.97 3.043-6.312v-.017c-.006-4.367-3.43-7.787-7.8-7.788zm3.787 12.972c-1.134.96-4.862 3.405-6.772 4.643V16.67c0-.414-.335-.75-.75-.75h-.396c-3.66 0-6.318-2.476-6.318-5.886 0-3.534 2.768-6.302 6.3-6.302l4.147.01h.002c3.532 0 6.3 2.766 6.302 6.296-.003 1.91-.942 3.844-2.514 5.176z"
        ) {
          var uniq_id = uniqID(20);
          $(current).find("svg").eq(i).parent().addClass(uniq_id);

          reply_array.push(uniq_id);
        }
      }
    });

    $("." + reply_array[0]).trigger("click");
```

The above code is used to click reply icon on tweet.
But I don't know how to write message in the popup of reply. I mean there is no textarea or text box in reply. There are only div. How to input text in div and then click on reply button.

Comment: Focus the div that has `contenteditable=true` attribute and then use document.execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: I am using the above example but focus() is not working. and also text is not changing. I am using below code
var replyInterval = setInterval(function () {
      const el = $("div[contenteditable=true]");
      if (el) {
        el.css("border", "2px solid red");
        el.focus();
        el.select();
        document.execCommand("insertText", true, "testing");
      }
      clearInterval(replyInterval);
    }, 1000);