# Google Chome Extension: Not able to do pass angular validation by javascript

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am working on google chrome extension project and wanted to insert login credentials to Angular based website through external javascript like

```
document.getElementByID("username").value="abc";
document.getElementByID("password").value="*****";
```

but when I click on Submit button it will not submit the form due to the validation ng-untouch by  Angular.

Please suggest me how can i pass the validation so that I can login.

Comment: Try [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: Thank you very much , I apply the code which you suggest and it work for me.