# Replace text on gmail using js

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, gmail, range

I am working on a chrome extension, which replaces part of the text. It does not work as expected on Gmail though.

Scanario:

**Gmail composer has following text -**

i am now to this.

i can do this.

**I want to replace it to -**

i am new to this.

i can do this.

However, whenever I execute the code, it does not replace the text on the correct location.
It sees where my cursor was and appends the text there instead of replacing the intended text.
This snippet works on other websites, which have contenteditable editors.

My current implementation looks like the following:

```
const range = document.createRange();
const ele = <div tag element for 'i am now to this.' sentence>
// rangeStart and rangeEnd are the index which wraps word 'now'

range.setStart(ele.childNodes[0], rangeStart);
range.setEnd(ele.childNodes[0], rangeEnd);
const selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
setTimeout(()=>{
        document.execCommand(
          "insertText",
          false,
          "new"
        );
      },0)
```

Comment: The standard approach is to 1) focus the contentenditable element, 2) call SelectAll command, 3) call insertText command. See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried this solution but it resets the undo stack. I am not using inserting textNodes and replacing using innerHTML for the same reason and I am using document.execCommand to maintain and have a seamless undo experience too. Is there any way to replace the text without messing the undo stack ?

Comment: execCommand always preserves the undo stack so I guess you've encountered a bug in the browser.

Comment: @wOxxOm maybe that's the reason it is marked for depreciation in few years.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that might go wrong about it.

One is that I noticed the `div` initially containing a single textNode  with some text switched to a node containing multiple textNodes with exactly the same over all text and that can create a number of problems considering that you are operating only  with `children[0]`.

Another thing that didn't work for me was the document executing the `isertText`

How so ever something that worked for me:

```js
        var range = document.createRange();
        var rangeStart = el.innerText.indexOf(s);
        var rangeEnd = rangeStart + s.length;
        var selection = window.getSelection();

        range.setStart(el.childNodes[0], rangeStart);
        range.setEnd(el.childNodes[0], rangeEnd);

        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(ss))
```

My entire testing scenario:

```js
(()=>{
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var n = all.length;
    var find = (s)=>{
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var el = all[i];
            var text  = el && el.childNodes && el.childNodes[0] && el.childNodes[0].wholeText;
            if (text && text.match(s)) {
                result.push(el);
            }
        }
        return result.length ? result : false;
    }
    ;

    var replacer = (s,ss)=>(el)=>{
        try {
        var range = document.createRange();
        var rangeStart = el.innerText.indexOf(s);
        var rangeEnd = rangeStart + s.length;
        range.setStart(el.childNodes[0], rangeStart);
        range.setEnd(el.childNodes[0], rangeEnd);
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(ss))
        }catch(ex){
            
        }

    }
    ;

    var elements = find('now');

    if (elements) {
        elements.map(replacer('now', 'new'))
    }

}
)(window);
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this solution but it resets the undo stack. I am not using inserting textNodes and replacing using innerHTML for the same reason. That's why I am using document.execCommand to maintain and have a seamless undo experience too. Is there any way to replace the text without messing the undo stack ?