# Problem putting text in HTML input field using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm a new developer trying to make a autofill chrome extension.
I manage to retrieve an input from the user but I cannot manage to put that input in the input box on a site.
I am trying this on the supreme webshop.

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  let name = message.txt;
  let nameField = document.getElementsByClassName('order_billing_name');
  nameField.value = name;
  console.log(nameField.value);
  }
```

I get the correct text in the nameField.value console log but the text does not show up on the site.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does not return a single element

Comment: Use `nameField[0].value` instead of just `nameField.value` or `forEach` method in case you have more than 1 element with the `order_billing_name` class name https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: See also [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I’m sorry but I still don’t completely understand. I console logged the getElement to understand more what it actually was. I found out that the get element is the complete div of the html input. Which parameter do I have to change to the text in the html form? Or is this the wrong way of thinking?