# Programmatically insert text into input field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm writing a chrome extension to programmatically fill out a form. My initial attempt was to set the `value` directly, e.g.: `document.getElementById('input-field').value = 'test';`. Unfortunately, it seems like the form has some code which disables the submit button until the user has pressed a key, and just setting the `value` attribute doesn't enable the button.

My other strategy is to use `dispatchEvent` with an `InputEvent`, e.g. something like:

```
var e = new InputEvent("insertText", {
  data: "f",
  bubbles: true,
  composed: true,
  inputType: "insertText",
  type: "input"
});
var inputField = document.getElementById('input-field');
inputField.dispatchEvent(e);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work at all (neither the input value changes nor does the form button get enabled).

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Dispatching the event needs to be combined with setting value separately

Comment: @charlietfl - so I need to first set the value, and then dispatch the input event? or somehow do both simultaneously?

Comment: Yes...set value then dispatch. Not guaranteeing it will work as we don't know what events the page js are using

Comment: remove the `#` from the `getElementById` string argument.

Comment: @charlietfl i used the chrome debugger to break on when the submit button attribute changes, and the call stack shows that it's being triggered by an InputEvent handler. unfortunately setting the value and then dispatching the inputevent didn't seem to work.

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)