# How can I fill a VUE.js page form input with chrome extension？

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a chrome extension for form auto fill, everything goes fine, but when I met a VUE.js page, the input value will not be changed with any text.

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  let script = ''
  let name = 'xxx'
  let pass = 'blah'
  script += 'document.getElementById("userName").value="' + name + '";'
  script += 'document.getElementById("pass").value="' + pass + '";'

  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: script
  })
})
```

When I use code like up there, for regular form, it works, but for vue.js page, the input seems to be filled, but when submit, the value will be cleared, then failed.

So I decide to change the VUE data value:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  let script = ''
  let name = 'xxxx'
  let pass = 'blahblahbal'

  script += 'document.querySelector(".page").__vue__.$children[1].$children[2].$children[0].form.model.username="' + name + '";'
  script += 'document.querySelector(".page").__vue__.$children[1].$children[2].$children[0].form.model.password="' + pass + '"'

  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: script
  })
})
```

the `document....` thing, works in the page console, but when execute form extension, it returns `__vue__` undefined.

I changed the `executeScript` from injected file, has the same result.

So, what can I do to fix this?

Thanks~

Comment: Try using execCommand in the script as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: @wOxxOm Great！That works！