# Programatically set controlled form values from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, google-chrome-extension, javascript-framework

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that makes the process of uploading to various social media platforms a little smoother.

This requires being able to set form inputs such as the Title and Description on, for example the [IGTV upload page](https://www.instagram.com/tv/upload/) . I have tried to do this with javascript such as `document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Title"]').value = 'My New Title'` and this *appears* to work.

However if you then 'focus' on the inputs once my code has filled them in, they revert to being empty again. I expect this is because they are being controlled by some frontend React code that is not being altered by my code.

Can you please suggest a way for me to set these inputs with my code in a way that the frontend framework will detect?

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: Thank you very much @wOxxOm you answered my problem perfectly.