# How to trigger enter keypress with jquery, on an angular input field

Tags: jquery, angular, tampermonkey

We are trying to implement a tampermonkey script on a 3rd party website which is built in angular.

We want to enter an order_id into the input, then trigger the keystroke enter(13).
The first part works fine, but it seems impossible to trigger the enter keystroke.

Does anyone have any experience with this and/or tips?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Bol order finder
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      https://partner.bol.com/sdd/outbound-orders/open/FBR?order=*
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    setTimeout(() => {
        //Take orderId from query params
        let orderArray = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('=');
        //Insert queryparams into input
        $($('[data-test=search-box]')[0].shadowRoot).find('input').val(orderArray[1]);
        //Focus the element
        $($('[data-test=search-box]')[0].shadowRoot).find('input').focus();
        setTimeout(() => {
            var ev = new CustomEvent('input');
            //Trigger input so angular knows the content has changed.
            $($('[data-test=search-box]')[0].shadowRoot).find('input')[0].dispatchEvent(ev);
            setTimeout(() => {
                ev = new CustomEvent('keypress');
                ev.which = ev.keyCode = 13;
                //Trigger enter on input field
                $($('[data-test=search-box]')[0].shadowRoot).find('input')[0].dispatchEvent(ev);
                },1000)
            },1000);
        },4000);
})();
```

Comment: Faking a keypress event may not work for a huge variety of reasons. You would be better off checking exactly what events the real enter keypress fires in the third-party DOM and calling that logic directly, if possible.

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did try to record what happens, but as soon as i press the pause button in chrome it already pauses before i hit enter, so i cant really record what happens without parsing all their js files which are very abstract.

Comment: You can see all the events bound to every element using the DOM inspector in devtools, you don't need to record user input.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the tip, I will try that