# Why document.getElementById.value = "XYZ" does not write to input text field?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, content-script

document.getElementById.value = "Rohan" does work partially, because I can see it in console log.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#addFirstName');
el.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Rohan');//This doesnot work
document.querySelector('#addFirstName').value = "Rohan"//works partially - able to see it print in console but not on webpage.
el.value = "Rohan"//works partially - able to see it print in console but not on webpage.
document.getElementById('addFirstName').value = "Rohan"// works partially - able to see it print in console but not on webpage.
console.log(document.getElementById('addFirstName').value) //prints Rohan
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})); //doesnot update anything on webpage
console.log(el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})))//prints true - event is dispatched but does nothing :(
```

```html
<div class="modal-content u__bgColor--reverse u__border--bottom u__border--top u__border--right u__border--left">
          <!--template bindings={}--><a class="modal--btn__close u__text--brand"></a>
<form _ngcontent-mtu-7="" autocomplete="off">
<div _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="add-address">
<div _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="body__p-all--normal u__border--bottom">
<div _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="form-input body__p-bottom--normal u__clearfix">
                            <span _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="col__6-12 col__12-12--xs body__p-left--none">
                                <label _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="form-input__label" data-content="First Name" for="addFirstName">
                                    <span _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="form-input__label-content">First Name</span>
                                </label>
                                <input _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="form-input__field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-untouched" data-automation-id="addressFnameField" id="addFirstName" maxlength="40" ngcontrol="addFirstName" type="text">
                                <error-messages _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="grid add-address__errorField" control="addFirstName" data-automation-id="addressFnameErrMsg"><!--template bindings={}--></error-messages>
                            </span>
                            <span _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="col__6-12 col__12-12--xs body__p-right--none">
                                <label _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="form-input__label" data-content="Last Name" for="lastName">
                                    <span _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="form-input__label-content">Last Name</span>
                                </label>
                                <input _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="form-input__field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-untouched" data-automation-id="addressLnameField" id="addLastName" maxlength="60" ngcontrol="addLastName" type="text">
                                <error-messages _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="grid add-address__errorField" control="addLastName" data-automation-id="addressLnameErrMsg"><!--template bindings={}--></error-messages>
                           </span>
                        </div>
                        <div _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="body__p-vertical--small">
                    <button _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="bttn bttn--primary add-address__address-savebtn disabled" data-automation-id="addressSavebutton" type="submit" disabled="">
                        <span _ngcontent-mtu-7="" class="bttn__content">Save</span>
                    </button>
                 </div>
                 </div>
</form>
</div>
```

In the inspect element when I open the webpage I see these warnings for few elements and the element which I am passing the value to through my chrome extension (updating the input text field) is also there:

Warning: [DOM] Found 3 elements with non-unique id #addFirstName:

The input field does not get updated.
But I can see it printed in console logs.
This is through the google-chrome-extension, I tried similar way on selenium as well and faced the same difficulty but I was able to overcome using send keys. Not sure what is causing this. Is it something related to HTML classes ?

I looked closely on the webpage using the inspect element and see there is a change in the class as soon as a manual click on the input field is done.

Could this be the reason for input text not getting updated on the webpage.
I also tried to trigger an event, but didn't help. Can anyone please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: @wOxxOm 

const input = document.querySelector('#addFirstName');

input.focus();

input.value = 'Rohan';

console.log(document.querySelector('#addFirstName').value)

input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false }));

I can see "Rohan" in console but not in UI

Comment: const input = document.querySelector('#addFirstName'); input.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Rohan'); //This command is not working.
console.log(document.querySelector('#addFirstName').value) input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false }));//Nothing in console and in UI

Comment: You have 5 live demos in your question. All of them have HTML **or** JavaScript which makes them all useless. Create a [mcve] which actually demonstrates the problem in a single live demo.