# Editing Input Fields in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension for a project of mine where it needs to test webpages for SQL Injection Vulnerabilities.
So far my extension can pull the number of input fields and print that number back into the addon.
There doesn't seem to be info online on how to edit the DOM the way I need to online.
Would anyone be able to help out here?
Even just get my extension to be able to put text into the input fields?

Now I know with the below, passing the input fields from the content script will need to be done through arrays, this was more of a concept.

Many thanks!

Here's my code.

**MANIFEST:**

```
{
"name": "SQL Injector",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "html/homepage.html",
  "default_title": "SQL Injector"
  }
}
```

**CONTENT SCRIPT:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    
var textInputs;
var searchInputs;
var passwordInputs;
var emailInputs;
    
if (document.querySelectorAll)
{
    textInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    console.log(textInputs);
}
else
{
    textInputs = [];
    var unfiltered = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        i = unfiltered.length,
        input;
    while(i--)
    {
        input = unfiltered[i];
        if (!input.type || input.type === 'text')
        {
            textInputs.push(input);
        }
    }
}
    
if (document.querySelectorAll)
{
    searchInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=search]');
    console.log(searchInputs);
}
else
{
    searchInputs = [];
    var unfiltered = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        i = unfiltered.length,
        input;
    while(i--)
    {
        input = unfiltered[i];
        if (!input.type || input.type === 'search')
        {
            searchInputs.push(input);
        }
    }
}
    
if (document.querySelectorAll)
{
    passwordInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=password]');
    console.log(passwordInputs);
}
else
{
    passwordInputs = [];
    var unfiltered = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        i = unfiltered.length,
        input;
    while(i--)
    {
        input = unfiltered[i];
        if (!input.type || input.type === 'password')
        {
            passwordInputs.push(input);
        }
    }
}
    
    
if (document.querySelectorAll)
{
    emailInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=email]');
    console.log(emailInputs);
}
else
{
    emailInputs = [];
    var unfiltered = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        i = unfiltered.length,
        input;
    while(i--)
    {
        input = unfiltered[i];
        if (!input.type || input.type === 'email')
        {
            emailInputs.push(input);
        }
    }
}


var totalInputs = textInputs.length + searchInputs.length + passwordInputs.length + emailInputs.length;
    
sendResponse({count: totalInputs})
})
```

**SQL INJECTION JS:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 'hi', setCount)
})
  
function setCount (res) {
document.getElementById("returnValue").innerHTML = `${res.count} total inputs on the page.`;
    
var items = [];
    
for(var i = 1; i <= res.count; i++) {
  item = '<div class="ui input"><input type="text" placeholder="Input">';
  items.push(item);
}

$('.searchfield').append(items.join("<br>"));
}
}, false)
```

**SQL INJECTION HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="../packages/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href= "../packages/semantic-ui/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/default.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../packages/semantic-ui/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="ui fixed menu inverted navbar">
        <a href="" class="brand item">SQL & XSS Tool</a>
        <a href="sqlinjection.html" class="item">SQL Injection</a>
        <a href="xss.html" class="item">Cross Site Scripting</a>
        <a href="urlencoder.html" class="item">URL Encoder/Decoder</a>
        <a href="education.html" class="item">Education</a>
    </nav> <!-- end nav -->

    <main class="ui page grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="ui message main">
                    <h1 class="ui header">SQL Injection!</h1>
                    <p>Here we will find the input fields found on the page, and will be able to run atacks against them.</p>
                    <p id="returnValue"></p>
                    <div class="searchfield"></div>
                    <script src="sqlinjection.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your content script can change the value of those inputs. See also [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: Oh nice! I'll give that a look, thanks!

Comment: That worked a treat! Thanks. You can see in my content that all it does is add up the total inputs and send to the sqlinjection.js. How can I have a button in my sqlinjection.html that then calls the content to replace the text on command?