# Injecting a chrome extension "value change script" of an input doesn't work without a keypress event

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events

I am new to Angular and Chrome extensions. I need to get a request from a local api and paste the result in an input and press a button. The form is made using Angular but when triggering the `document.getElementById("input-id").value = 'text'` and trigger the form submitting button, the input value doesn't seem to be updated and the submitted request has an empty value for the input. It works if i type something and then delete (triggering a keypress event).

Is there a way to write the text value given by the api that mimics a keypress ?
This is a part of the code: 
popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startFunctionButton").click(function(){
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/testang", function(data, status) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                apiData[key] = value;
            });

            chrome.storage.sync.set({
                pp: apiData['data'],
            });
        }); 
    });

    $("#finishButton").click( async () => {
        let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            files: ["jquery-3.6.0.min.js"] }, 
          () => {
          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            function: testFunction,
          });
        });
});
```

This is the function:

```
function testFunction() {
  let ppa;
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['pp'], (result) => {
    ppa = result.pp;
  });

    setTimeout(() => {
        // $("#page-input-id").trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 0}));
        document.getElementById("page-input-id").value = ppa;
    },2000)
}
```

I tried:

1. Just updating the field
2. Triggering a javascript keydown, keyup event on the input or document
3. Focusing the input then triggering the events specified above
4. Injecting the JQuery code too and use the .trigger(JQuery.Event('keypress') function
5. Focusing, changing the values of another elements

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you, that saved me a lot of trouble