# Can't update value with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-plugins

I need to update a textare value with the chrome plugin. When I type directly into the console, the value is updated without any problems, but I cannot update the taxtarea value on some sites. I am able to access the textarea but cannot update the value with .value. Thank you very much to everyone who helped.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `<div class="plg">
    <input type="number" id="sureee" placeholder="Süre">
    <input type="file" id="plugingo">
    <label class="chkbx" id="clcc">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inpinp">
    <span class="x"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<style>
    
input[type="file"] {
    cursor: pointer !important;
    font: 300 14px sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    background: #212121;
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type="file"]::-ms-browse {
    background: #212121;
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.plg{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding:20px ;
}
#sureee{
padding:8px;
font-size:18px;
outline:none;
border:1px solid #fff;
width:100%;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.chkbx input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.chkbx {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.chkbx .x {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    border: 2px solid #d3d3be;
    border-radius: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.chkbx .x:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #d3d3be;
    border: 2px solid #d3d3be;
    border-radius: 40px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.chkbx :checked~.x:before {
    background: #fe7f2d;
    border-color: #fe7f2d;
    transform: translatex(25px);
}

.chkbx :checked~.x {
    border-color: #fe7f2d;
}

.chkbx {
    display: block;
}
</style>`;
    document.body.appendChild(div);



    var index = 0;
    var cl;
    function gg(comment) {





        var sure = Number(document.getElementById('sureee').value) * 1000;
        if (index <= comment.length - 1) {
            console.log(comment[index])

            cl = setTimeout(function () {
              
                var gonder = document.querySelector(".send-msg-btn");
                if (document.getElementById('inpinp').checked == true) {
                    
                    document.querySelector('textarea.chat-panel-input').value=comment[index];
                    
                    gonder.click();
                    index++;
                }
                gg(comment)
            }, sure);


        }



    }


    function clcz() {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function () {
            let parsedJSON = fileReader.result
            var comment = parsedJSON.split('\n');
            gg(comment)

        }
        fileReader.readAsText(document.getElementById('plugingo').files[0]);
    }


    document.getElementById('plugingo').addEventListener('change', () => {
        index = 0;
        document.getElementById('inpinp').click();
        clcz();
       
    })
}
```

Comment: [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help, I'll look into it right away.