# Update form input value by JQuery fails | Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a script to autofill an address form on webpage using jquery. The script updates the value in the fields but when I click else where the values go back to null. I assumed the input is expecting a keypress or click event on the fields so I tried that too. Same happens when I try to submit the form too.

```
$(function(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['fname','fstreetaddress','fcity','fstate','fpostalcode'],function(address){
        $(".address-form input[name=name]").trigger('keypress');
        //$(".address-form input[name=name]").trigger('focus');
        //$(".address-form input[name=name]").attr("value",address.fname);
        $("address-form input[name=name]").val(address.fname);
        $("address-form input[name='addressLineOne']").val(address.fstreetaddress);
        $("address-form input[name='City']").val(address.fcity);
        $("address-form input[name='State']").val(address.fstate);
        $("address-form input[name='postalCode']").val(address.fpostalcode);
    });
});
```

Also if I add something to the autofilled value using keyboard, it stays.

Comment: [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you so much, this solution works! But do you know how to solve this for a <select> input?

Comment: Try setting its value then use that line with dispatchEvent from the answer.