# Chrome Extension - input auto-changing, not dispatching the change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have an iframe that I'm trying to make auto filling by chrome extension. The value is changed well, but the app doesn't see the values, and I need to type it again for it to affect the form.

After googling, I do all the below code tries and more.

**What else can I do?**

```
function func3() {
    // setTimeout(function () {
    //
    // }, )
    let elId3 = "social-id-field";
    let input3 = document.getElementById(elId3);
    if (input3 != null) {

        //also tried that :
        // let ev = document.createEvent('Events');
        // ev.initEvent('keypress', true, true);
        // ev.keyCode = 13;
        // ev.which = 13;
        // ev.charCode = 13;
        // ev.key = 'Enter';
        // ev.code = 'Enter';
        input3.value = "123456789";
        // input3.dispatchEvent(ev);

        // let event = new Event('input', {bubbles: true});
        input3.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));


    }


}
```

Manifest:

```
...    
{
          "matches": [ "https://*.hf.paymeservice.com/service/field/*"],
          "all_frames": true,
          "css": ["style.css"],
          "js": ["jquery-3.6.0.min.js","factory54-payment.js"]
        }
        ...
```

this is the [page](https://www.factory54.co.il/checkout?stage=payment#payment)

Update:

Until I press enter inside the input it's won't work. Also, I see that it's happening only on this input.

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: It's still not working. Until I press enter inside the input. Also I see that it's happen only on this input.