# Google docs api, why can't insertText request be cleared with ctrl + z?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am using the google docs api, and am inserting text using:

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#InsertTextRequest

however, the inserted text is not removed when the user presses ctrl + z. How do I add my inserted text into the google docs undo buffer?

Comment: Try this: [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: Thanks, I can get it to insert text into a contenteditable div into the iframe that i am using to detect keydown events: document.getElementsByClassName('docs-texteventtarget-iframe')[0].body.firstChild. But, it doesn't seem to bubble up a keydown event that google docs uses to insert text.