# simulating keypress on Input on webpage using chrome.debugger.sendCommand

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, tampermonkey

I'm working on a TamperMonkey script to automate a few things for me on a webpage.

On this webpage there is also an input-field which is giving me some headaches.
I can enter values in the field, but it doesn't get validated and the submit button remains disabled.

I can select the input programmatically by using

```
elmtsInputs[0].select();
```

after which I can enter the value from my keyboard without any problem.

However if I try:

```
elmtsInputs[0].value = "0.5";
```

The value 0.5 appears briefly before it's being reset again to the default 0.0

So there is some sort of validation happening on the input-field that notices that the value wasn't typed.
Also when I type in an unauthorized value (basically any value greater than 1) it also shows a validation message to say the value is incorrect. So there is definitely validation happening.

I have tried multiple dispatchEvents but none of them worked.
After searching online I came across multiple sources that the problem is related to the `isTrusted:false`
issue where input coming from scripts are not trusted but keyboard input is.

When trying to look if there was any way to bypass this, I found some examples where the use of the Chrome Debugger was used a solution.

```
chrome.debugger.attach(target, "1.2", function() {
   chrome.debugger.sendCommand(target, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", arguments)
})
```

However, I haven't found any useable example on how to implement this.

Can someone shed some light on how this should be implemented?
Thank you.

Comment: Userscripts can't use `chrome` API, it's only for extensions. Try execCommand instead, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879322/enter-data-into-a-custom-handled-input-field/57900849)

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, that worked like a charm!

Comment: Can you share a working solution ?