# After setting value property, how to cause textarea to update as if it was user input?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm building a Chrome extension that enables the user to insert canned responses into Youtube comments on their channel. I insert the text using `textarea`'s value property:

```
getHighlightedComment().querySelector("textarea").value = cannedResponseText
```

The problem is, the `textarea` **doesn't adapt its size and the submit button doesn't get enabled until I type in another letter manually**.

[image]

[image]

I have a different extension installed that has a similar functionality that doesn't have these problems, so it must be possible.

**I already tried sending `keypress`/`keydown`/`keyup` events manually, but they seem to not work inside `textarea`s. Nothing happens in response to them.**

Comment: I don't see any `textarea` element in youtube comment form. They use a `contenteditable` editor. See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57879322).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! I actually found `execCommand` earlier but didn't use it because of deprecation. So you're saying that is still the right choice now in 2022 until there is an alternative?

Comment: It works, thank you! Although the element where I input text IS a `textarea` HTML element.

Comment: It may be the only choice for the next 20 years, for all I know.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to trigger some event on your field after actual change [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856602/9994697) is how you can deal with it.

UPD.

> I tried sending keypress/keydown/keyup events but it seems they don't work inside textareas. Nothing happens.

I guess it is more about `onchange` event.

Also you need to check the CSS of your textarea - [rows are not hardcoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-rows), height and max-height is not hardcoded (has value 'auto').

Here are some workarounds to update it with JS - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25621277/9994697

Comment: I tried sending `keypress`/`keydown`/`keyup` events but it seems they don't work inside `textarea`s. Nothing happens.

Comment: not sure, but are you also tried dispatching input event?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).