# What are the javascript events that can trigger an action on an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, linkedin-api

I am building up a plugin that needs to perform a search on linkedin main search bar, using jquery & js.

When using it normally, you would have to click on it, which expands a search box, and press enter to search for the value your entered:

[image]

However, for some reason, I am unable to trigger the click on the search input.
I tried with click, mousein, mouseenter, focusin events, using jquery, but it does not trigger any action. I also try to simulate a click, but no luck.

I went further and tried the same actions on the parent divs with class "global-nav-typeahead", "search-global-typeahead" and "global-nav__search" but no luck.

you can see the structure here:

[image]

Therefore my question is, is there any other js event I am missing that could cause the search box to open? I'm not sure which event is this search box listening to in order to appear.

What other events could be triggered? Is it possible linkedin has some kind of protection about programmatic events? and if yes, how to go around it?

Comment: Events don't trigger actions, actions trigger the events.

Comment: Calling `.focus()` on the element works for me.

Comment: ... and listeners are triggered by events

Comment: @wOxxOm when I do focus on the input it's not doing anything. How do you submit the value entered to trigger a search? I'm using this: `$('input.search-global-typeahead__input').focus().val("John Smith").trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 })).submit();`

Comment: It does enter the value, but the search is never triggered

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57879322)