# Properly passing a selector to a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass selector of the First Name field at that page: https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/4509387877809921038 to the `replaceValue` function (source: [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879322/enter-data-into-a-custom-handled-input-field))

```
replaceValue('#registrant\.firstName','my_name')

function replaceValue(selector, value) {
  const el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (el) {
    el.focus();
    el.select();
    if (!document.execCommand('insertText', false, value)) {
      // Fallback for Firefox: just replace the value
      el.value = 'new text';
    }
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})); // usually not needed
  }
  return el;
}
```

But it doesn't work for me. As I am not familiar with web technologies I am probably making some dumb mistake. Can you please help?

EDIT: I did some tests in the console as @DiegoDeVita suggested:
[image: SyntaxErrors]

EDIT2: A little more testing:

[image: Null returns]

Comment: Maybe escaping the . was superfluos? `#registrant.firstName`. Anyway in general I suggest you to address each single problem separately. To understand if the selector is working you could just run document.querySelector(selector) on its own on console and check if that part work and go to the next

Comment: the selector should be a string enclosed in double or single quotes

Comment: . is only a special character when working with regEx, so unless you are doing an regex search you don't need to escape it

Comment: your edit suggest the query selector isn't working can you include your HTML so we can see what actually you are trying to find it currently should be an element with the id registrant and the class firstName ie `<input id=registrant  class=firstName  />`

Comment: The field is defined as:
`<input type="text" data-bind="'css':{'inputError': verificationFailed}, 'attr':{'id':'registrant.' + name,  'maxlength':maxSize, 'tabindex':tabIdx}, 'hasFocus':isSelected, 'value':selectedAnswer, 'valueUpdate': 'afterkeydown'" class="form-control maxCharLimit" id="registrant.firstName" maxlength="128" tabindex="2">`

Comment: The website is https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/4509387877809921038
I took the CSS selector ('#registrant\.firstName) with the Firefox Inspector tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that there are dot characters within the element ID which makes writing selectors more complicated.

The linked page has the following element:

```html
<input id="registrant.firstName" ... />
```

Since the `.` has a special meaning within CSS selector context. It needs to be escaped with a `\`. The selector `#registrant.firstName` would match an element with *id* `registrant` and *class* `firstName`. Whereas `#registrant\.firstName` matches an element with *id* `registrant.firstName`.

The reason why you're having issues is because `\` has a special meaning in JavaScript string context. It escapes the character that directly follows the `\`. If you where to log the string `"#registrant\.firstName"` you would see the output `#registrant.firstName`, because the `\` escapes the `.` and is not a actual present within the string.

To correctly match the element you'll have to escape the `\` in the string literal. `"#registrant\\.firstName"` If you where to log this string you would see the output `#registrant\.firstName`, because the first `\` escapes the second `\` (`"\\"` is a string containing a single `\` character).

Comment: Ha, now it is working perfectly. What an inception... Thank you!