# Chrome extension how to enter text in any selected text field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, textfield

I am making a Chrome extension that generates nicknames when you press Ctrl+Shift+U, and it should automatically enter the generated name in the selected text field, if one is selected. My problem is that there are many types of text fields, the most basic being input. This is currently my function that generates the nickname, which works for input fields and textarea fields, but for nothing else.

```js
//Nickname gets generated here
//...

var inp = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var txt = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
    
for (var i=0;i<inp.length;i++) {
    if (inp[i] == document.activeElement) {
        inp[i].value = nick;
    }
}
    
for (var i=0;i<txt.length;i++) {
    console.log(txt[i]);
    if (txt[i] == document.activeElement) {
        txt[i].innerHTML = nick;
    }
}
```

Basically, what I think I would need, is some kind of function that can act like the user is typing the name, without directly changing the value of a field.

Comment: Try [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: That seems to work. I don't know how I couldn't find this question since I have googled this for a few days now, but thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: This seems to work in most cases, but if I try to press Ctrl+Shift+U in the discord message field, everything starts to behave in a very weird way. First of all the "Send message" placeholder doesn't dissapear, and second, if I select the entered text, it automatically unselects for some reason. Thrid, I can't remove the entered text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), with a bit of modification, I got it to work. This is my final code:

```js
//Nickname gets generated here
//...

const keyboardEventInit = {bubbles:false, cancelable:false, composed:false, key:'', code:'', location:0};
const element = document.activeElement;

if (element) {

    element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", keyboardEventInit));
    element.value = nick;
    element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", keyboardEventInit));
    element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}));

}
```

Comment: Somehow this does not work for a lot of pages, linkedin, twitter ....