# Unable to edit the value of an element in an EventListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, calculator

I made an extension that changes messes with the google calculator, but i am unable to edit the value of an element inside an Event Listener.

```
//the value of the calculator:
let output = document.getElementById("cwos")

//the equals/calculate button:
const equals = document.querySelector("div[jsname='Pt8tGc']")


//this edits the calculators value:
output.textContent = 0

console.log(output.textContent)


equals.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked")

    //this doesn't edit the calculators value, and i don't know why
    output.textContent = 0

    console.log(output.textContent)

})
```

Thanks if you can answer.

Comment: [This should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/5wfbons1/). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)