# JS Greasemonkey Input Text Box

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm a newbie JS programmer, just trying to do some automation here and there with extensions like Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/Violentmonkey.
I ran into a wall that I can't find a solution, already tried to search for it for days and still can't figure it out.

The problem is this: there's page buttons (like a book), it can to go back, forward, and set a number to skip to X that page.
I can click on both back and forward with no problem. My only issue is making use of the input box (not sure if that's how it's called).

The box works like this: you set any number inside and press ENTER (only way to confirm/submit the value change) and them it'll skip to that page if the page exists.
One weird thing for me is that I tried changing it manually from 1 (default) to 3, them setting to 2 on script (with x.value) and when I confirm it manually, it goes to page 3 and not page 2 (even though it's showing 2 on UI and also on .value). So I though at least the value set I got, but it seems that even that I couldn't make.

Also changing the value="1" on DevTools to anything else doesn't change the UI and also don't register the input change, since when I press enter it just ignore my value.

This is the HTML shown on DevTools of the input box:

```
<input class="number" value="1" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; text-align: center;">
```

I'm not using jQuery (simply because I don't know how to use it), but if it's necessary I can learn!

[Screen of the HTML structure on DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64N8m.png)

[Console.log with some info about the element I could search online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxFTb.png)

I don't know anything else I could provide to help further assistance.
If there's anything, please let me know and thank you for helping!

Comment: Try [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll look and try everything there. Thank you!

Comment: @wOxxOm just tried for a little bit. Changing the value now works with your method, thank you! 
Still unable to make the submit/confirm. I'm gonna try more as soon as I'm back home. 
I'm already happy that I'm seeing progress on it! Really thank you!!

Comment: THAAAAANKKKK YOOOUUU! I managed to do it! Using your solution to change the value them a simple el.dispatchEvent did the trick! 
Again and again, thank you!

Comment: Please do not edit your question with a solution. You can create an answer for your own question.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thank you both @LeeTaylor and @gre_gor! I'll make sure to use those tips if I need to post something else again.

Answer (score 0):

With @wOxxOm's solution I was able to do it!
All it needed was his solution (see comments) to change the inside value of the textbox and them a el.dispatchEvent with enter on it's key made the submit work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).