# Having Issue to Use Received Message From Popup in Current Page In Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Using Chrome Extension Manifest 3, I am trying to send and use a message from popup to current active tab/page

in my manifest I have

```
{

    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My Ext",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "Testing",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["content-script.js"]
   }
 ]

}
```

In my `popup.html` JS script I have which will trigger when user clicks on `.send-message` button in popup

```
  $(document).on("click", ".send-message", function () {
   chrome.tabs.query({
                active: true,
                currentWindow: true
            }, function (tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                    code: "Hello Input"
                });
            });
          });
```

In `content-script.js` I have

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request.code);
        $('#input').val(request.code);
        $('#input').text(request.code);
    }
);
```

I have added the jQuery on top of my `content_scripts` to inject the jQuery there too (Not sure this is a correct and smart way to do it!)

I am able to send the `request.code` message to page as the `console.log(request.code);` is logging out the message in current page console but the  `$('#input').val(request.code);  $('#input').text(request.code);` is not working!

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here and how I can fix this?

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: Thanks for comment but it looks like the `Document.execCommand()` is deprecated!

Comment: Deprecation doesn't matter.