# Fill Google Places form programatically from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-places-api

I am trying to auto-fill the shipping information on the checkout page of Walmart from a Chrome extension.

The issue i am running into is that Walmart uses the Places API to suggest addresses and when i try to fill the form input like so:

```
document.getElementsByName("addressLineOne")[0].value = "12345 SouthWest 123 Drive";
```

The input resets if i click anywhere on the page:

[image]

Since i am filling it from a chrome extension it doesn't seem like i can modify the form through the places API since i cannot access the page's scripts.

I have tried a few things without any luck:

- Focusing the input before setting the value
- Selecting the input before setting the value
- Removing the placeholder, focusing, selecting, and finally adding the value to the input

Is there a way i can programmatically fill in this form where it wont just reset?

Comment: Try [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: Thanks for that link, i was able to look for an alternative way after seeing that "execCommand" was depricated but it led me on the right path

Comment: It can be used despite deprecation. There's also no real need to copy the other answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code snippet i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69761966/6460122):

```
function imitateKeyInput(el, keyChar) {
  if (el) {
    const keyboardEventInit = {bubbles:false, cancelable:false, composed:false, key:'', code:'', location:0};
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", keyboardEventInit));
    el.value = keyChar;
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", keyboardEventInit));
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})); // usually not needed
  } else {
    console.log("el is null");    
  }
}
```

I was able to just use this function to fill out the form without issue by calling the function and passing the element and value like so:

```
imitateKeyInput(document.getElementsByName("addressLineOne")[0], "12345 SouthWest 123 Drive");
```

--

Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)'s suggestion, i was able to mimic the deprecated execCommand functionality like this and solve this issue.