# Send text messages on WhatsApp Web?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to capture a text from my chrome extension and have it automatically go to whatsapp web text box.

Until a month ago I was able to send a message using the following code:

```js
 var input = document.querySelector('[contenteditable~=true]');
        input.innerHTML = message;
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```

Comment: Didn't succeed yet to put the message there programmatically, It's also capturing mouse simulation clicks and not working. Will try this tomorrow.

Comment: @piyush-pranjal tks bro, I'm trying to find a solution too. If I find a solution, I'll share it with you.

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
function send_text(text) {
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.setData('text', text);
const event = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
      clipboardData: dataTransfer,
      bubbles: true
    });
let el = document.querySelector('#main .copyable-area [contenteditable="true"][role="textbox"]')
el.dispatchEvent(event)
}
send_text(your_text)
```

Or

[See Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879322/enter-data-into-a-custom-handled-input-field)

Comment: Is this working? Why is this answer no accepted? How did you figure this out?

Comment: Working Solution!!