# Javascript - trigger click event on div after updating input value programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to trigger a mouse click event programmatically using Javascript on a div, but only after the value of an input is updated, also using Javascript.

It is updating the value successfully but the mouse click event is not taking place.

Please note that the input is not contained inside the div that I am trying to click on.

Please also note that there are multiple `inputs` and the following code is inside a loop for all the `inputs`.

```
// input node reference
const inputElem = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='number']")[index];
// bind "change" event listener
inputElem.addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e.target.value));
// programmatically change the input's value
inputElem.value = 5;
// simulate mouse click
var someDiv = document.getElementById("root");
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
    "view": window,
    "bubbles": true,
    "cancelable": false
});
someDiv.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

P.S. - This is for a chrome extension, to manipulate the inputs of a webpage, and those inputs require mouse click outside input (or enter key press), for the cart to update.

P.P.S - The console does say `Appboy: Trigger event custom_event did not match any trigger conditions.` All I know is this message is related to React JS. So this page possibly has React applied to the `inputs` that I am trying to manipulate.

Comment: See [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: I tried `execCommand` method you showed in your answer, but it has the same issue, value updates but click doesn't get triggered

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you think it could be because the `inputs` possibly have React JS applied to them?

Comment: If you can share the site you're working with, it'd be a lot easier to diagnose the problem and help. Thanks.

Comment: This is the [website](https://app.ordermentum.com/) but the page (cart) can't be accessed without login, I am happy to share login privately to you as I think publicly sharing it is not allowed on StackOverflow. How do I share login? Thanks BTW.