# Set Value to input field but fail to trigger validation using tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

So I am attempting to write a auto login script for this website
https://www.urbtix.hk/login/?redirect=%252Fperformance-detail%253FeventId%253D9269%2526performanceId%253D41302
but I fail to trigger the validation for the input field, so I cant actually unlock the login button.

I have observed the event fired using `monitorEvents($0)` in chrome devtool, and I see there is a change event, so attempt to simulate that too but still I fail to trigger the validation. Any clue on how I can get a string filled into the input filed?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         urbtixLoginAutoFill
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.urbtix.hk/login/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=urbtix.hk
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==
function setControl(elemSelector, value) {
    var zInput = $(elemSelector);
    zInput.val(value);
    console.log("setControl", zInput);
    // var changeEvent = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    // changeEvent.initEvent("change", true, true);
    // zInput[0].dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
    const change = new Event("change");
    zInput[0].dispatchEvent(change);
}
const sleep = async (milliseconds) => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        return setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
    });
};

var _username = "username";
var _password = "password";
var userInputSelector = "input[name='loginId']";
var passwordInputSelector = "input[name='password']";
var loginButtonSelector =
    "#root > div > div.main___3Egpk > div > div > div.field-row.field-row-login-button > div.button-wrapper.login-button.blue.disabled";

$(document).ready(async function () {
    await window.addEventListener("load", function load() {
        console.log("before load");
        setControl(userInputSelector, _username);
        setControl(passwordInputSelector, _password);
        console.log("after load");
        // $(loginButtonSelector).removeClass("disabled");
    });
});
```

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).