# Word Office online insert/edit text using browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ms-word

I'm developing a chrome extension which can insert/edit paragraph on World Office web/browser version that use onedrive as the text editor platform, at first I'm inserting the text via simple HTML DOM to inserting a text but it will not saved or disappeared if we click on the text editor. Is there any way to correctly insert or edit a text on Word Office web ?

here's the code that I've tried:

content_script.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(sender.tab ?
    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
    "from the extension");
  var node = document.querySelectorAll(".OutlineElement");
  var clone = node[node.length-1].cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementsByClassName("OutlineGroup")[0].appendChild(clone);
  console.log(window.getSelection());
  if (request.method == "getSelection")
    sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
  else
    sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, 
    function(tabs) {
      console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li'))
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "getSelection"}, 
      function(response){
        text.innerHTML = response.data;
      });
    });
```

this method will replicate a text on the word editor but the cloned text will disappeared or not saved after we click on other area part of the text(word) editor

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work on my end

Comment: Did you focus the element with `contenteditable` attribute first?

Comment: i've tried to focus on the `contenteditable` elements, it's still doesn't work and just give me false result if I console log it

Comment: @AlvinTamaarsa I’m wondering if you managed to do it? I’m having a similar problem. I was thinking about dispatching a key press event. Thanks

Comment: @Ben unfortunately the problem is still unresolved