# Tampermonkey enters values into web form but are cleared on submit

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am using Tampermonkey and the script segment below to fill in some values into a web form, a timesheet actually. When the form loads the script runs and enters the values - this is working fine. The problem is when I click the form's `Submit` button nothing is submitted and the form is cleared. Entering the same text by hand works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Or what other approach can I try?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fill the timesheet
// @namespace    
// @version      0.1
// @description  
// @author       
// @match        https://timesheet.employer.com/employees/timesheet/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

var days = document.getElementsByClassName('timesheet_days');

for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    var day = days[i];
    console.log(day);

    var box = day.getElementsByClassName("Timesheet__input")[0];
    box.value = "8h 00m";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879322/enter-data-into-a-custom-handled-input-field)

Comment: Use the more modern `.forEach()` method instead of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879322/enter-data-into-a-custom-handled-input-field/57900849#57900849). The issue is if Tampermonkey changes the `.value` field for a text box then the `isTrusted` field for the DOM element is set `false` and the timesheet server rejects the text. I say that like I know what I am talking about, which for sure I don't, but that is what I understand from the link above. One way around this is to paste the value as though it came from the clipboard.

This code is working fine -

```
        var box = day.getElementsByClassName("Timesheet__input")[0];
        box.focus();
        box.value = ""; // clear any prefilled value

        const el = document.querySelector('input');
        el.focus();
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, '8h 00m');
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})); // usually not needed
```